# Where to store the DB connection details for a JSP code

Tags: database, jsp, jdbc, connection

I am connecting to an oracle DB from a JAVA code which in turn is called from a JSP page. But i am confused as to whether a normal configuration/properties file is the best place to store the connection details to the DB.

Apologies if this sounds too silly.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It depends very much on the details of your deployment and the organisation who will deploy it.

Comment: The most common and portable way is using a JNDI datasource definition as explained [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) for Tomcat.

Comment: Make sure if you put the configuration/properties file under the webapp folder that you put it under WEB-INF so users can't get to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the Responses,

I went ahead with the Data sources and was able to do it successfully in my scenario :)

Appreciate all the help.